# The application does not find the path to the files?

Tags: html, css, spring, thymeleaf

Have next problem.
When i do right click to index.html and then open file in browser i see my html page with my css style, everything ok
Path in html page

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

When i run Spring Boot Application + Thymeleaf, and then go to http://localhost:8099/ i see only html page.

I try to add static folder and change path, but in this casion, css file did not open.  right click -> open in browser --> load only empty html page

```
 <link href="resources/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="resources/static/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

folder structure in picture.

[image]

folder css the same

Comment: `src/main/resources` is the root of the classpath. You should access your resources with `/static/css/style.css`

Comment: Ok, and what i must to do in my Eclipse, that get access to my resources in folder static/css/style.css ?

Comment: Nothing. As that will, normally, be exposed by Spring Boot already. Unless you decided to configure stuff yourself and/or added an `@EnableWebMvc`.